# php seems to be waiting for a response after mysql query has completed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code snippet:

```
$sql = "insert into table_new select * from table_old";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql2 = "select * from table_new";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

The first sql takes some 2-3 hours to complete.  I am monitoring it using a mysql console and I can see when it completes, but the PHP script does not continue.  It almost seems to be still waiting on the mysql response.

What could have happen here? and how can I mitigate against it?

NOTE:  I am aware that I should be using mysqli, but I am in a legacy product and have to use mysql for the remainder.

Comment: Why do you execute twice the same query ?

Comment: Are you sure it's completing and not timing out?

Comment: You can shorten the time on the first query by dropping the indexes on the table and rebuild them after the query is completed.

Comment: Why does one execute a query which takes hours to execute from within php?

Comment: @bastienbot typo now fixed

Comment: @BrianH. when I look in the mysql console and check the table the query has completed successfully

Comment: @JanTuroň  This sql is paraphrased and I have already shortened the execution down as much as I am able.

Comment: @arkascha so that you can run it in CLI mode against multiple schemas in an interactive script - or better yet why would you do it any particular way.

Comment: But, the PHP script may be timing out before running the second query.

Comment: @Gordy Running queries on a command line is easier with a simple sql script, I'd say. Much more flexible too, since you don't need all the code for setting up the connection. You can do that directly on shell level and get more direct feedback. Note that I don't want to say it is a bad thing to do. I only asked what the reasons are for these _two_ languages where only one is required.

Comment: @BrianH. the PHP script is being run in CLI mode and is still running

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to [GEARMAN](http://gearman.org/). It allows you to have process in background.

Comment: This is not really an answer to why PHP is waiting on MySQL and MySQL thinks it is finished.

Comment: Theory is when you know everything but nothing works. Practice is when everything works but no one knows why. Just kidding ;)